# Is there a manufacturer that produces an analog ohmmeter specifically for

Tags: analog, ohmmeter

Does anyone know of a manufacturer that produces a specific type of analog ohmmeter for testing the automotive relays equipped with silicon diodes ?  I have heard that it is a newer type and has an amplitude test voltage of 3 volts dc, specifically for testing semiconductors ie transistors,si and ge diodes and leds.  Any new digital  dmms do not have enough amplitude test voltage to test spike suppression diodes mounted in parallel  inside automotive relays . An instructor of vehicle electronics has stated that they are newer analog ohmmeter out there with a 3 volt amplitude test voltage.So far I have not found one yet.    if you can help pls respond

Comment: I think it is a "pulse" meter, so it can't damage the "DUT". I used (a long time ago) such an "active" multimeter for testing only "one" component on a populated PCB board.

Answer (score 4):

If so, it would likely be an automotive specialty meter not a meter aimed at general electronics.

The kind of current that would be required to cause the diode to conduct on an automotive relay (as low as 50 ohms coil) could be damaging to ordinary semiconductors, so you'd have to be careful with it around electronics.

Analog meters generally have enough current on the lowest resistance range to cause a silicon diode to conduct. For example, the venerable [Simpson 260](http://www.simpson260.com/downloads/simpson_260-6_and_6m_user_manual.pdf) has a short-circuit current of 125mA on the 0~2000 ohm range and an open circuit voltage of 1.5V. So even with a 50 ohm coil it will read differently one direction vs. the other and allow the presence (and non-shorted state) of the diode to be verified (and the coil resistance to be verified).

Comment: P.S. you might find better advice regarding sourcing specialty automotive test products at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/, assuming it is a permitted type of question.